# How to get the args that went into a dask client submit call?

Tags: dask

client = ...
   fut = client.submit(fun, args)

Is there some accessor to get the args from the submit call or should we wrap with something?

UPDATE:

So basically when debugging the response (on error especially), it is often useful to get the full task spec. I think of this as the (fun, args, ...) stuff.

Previously, I have created my own wrappers for errors and args and returned result in kind of dict(status=..., args=..., result=..., ...) dict.

Just wondering if there is a built-in pattern that I should be using or pushing folks towards.

Calling client.recreate_... doesn't necessarily give you the args that went into the submitted function.

Comment: Can you say more about what this will help you achieve?

Comment: Hey, just updated with a bit of flavour. I think I wrote the original quickly from a phone on the way out the door.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "no", these are not stored anywhere convenient today.

The args and kwargs are stored in the scheduler, but not in a particularly accessible form.  Typically in cases like these I record these things somewhere else as you seem to already be doing.

Comment: This probably makes sense anyway because dask is not limiting the user from sending HUGE args. And storing these args only makes sense if you follow good practice and keep args as minimal refs/config etc.